# Why my static variable is undefined after assigning it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, fetch

I'm a beginner in TypeScript and I can't get why my variable response is still undefined although I assign it with the result in my fetch.

Here is my code :

```
class UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI implements UserInfoRepository {
  private static response: Promise<any> | undefined = undefined;

  constructor() {}

  init = async (accessToken: string) => {
    const headers = ...

    const url = ...
    const opts = ...

    UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response = (await fetch(url, opts)).json();

    console.log('response? ', await UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response);
  };

  getResponse = () => {
    return UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response;
  };
}
```

then, in another function, I did :

```
const userInfo = new UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI();
userinfo.init(my_access_token)
```

At this time, it's printing `response? ...my_fetch_response...`
So it's not undefined.
But, when I do next :

```
console.log('the response here will be undefined : ', (await getResponse()))
```

I get : `the response here will be undefined : undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the point of using a static field if it's being populated from an instance method. Seems wrong. You'd ideally either use a static method to populate it, or use a method (static or instance) that just returns the value without populating a field, or use an instance method and an instance field.

Comment: Aside from that when you say "*At this time, it's printing*" I doubt you're running the operations in the correct order. `init` is asynchronous, so it might be running *after* the latter `console.log`. I see no guarantee that the two would run in the correct order - I'd suggest chaining onto the promise returned from `init` or alternatively using `await userinfo.init(my_access_token)` and making sure the code runs after that is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is missing keyword await. [`response.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) is also returning a promise.

```
UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response = await (await fetch(url, opts)).json();
console.log('response? ', UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response);
```

Also `UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.init` is an async function, which returns a promise so you'll need to await for it.

```
const userInfo = new UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI();
await userinfo.init(my_access_token);
console.log(getResponse());
```

`UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response` returns undefined because of the asynchronous nature of promise. Since you're not awaiting for the function calls as I specified above then at the time `UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response` is printed then the value is not yet available.

Comment: You will have to fix another line:
```console.log('response? ', UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response);```. This no longer needs `await`.

Comment: Included the console

Comment: It turns out adding await keyword before my init() 
```await userinfo.init(my_access_token);``` resolve completely my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `getResponse()` be async function.

```js
    getResponse = async () => {
        return await UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response;
    };
```

You also need to do this:

```js
   await userinfo.init(my_access_token)
```

Comment: Thank you that was it ! Why is my variable undefined and not returning a promise without the async keyword?

Comment: It depends on the sequence you call it. If you are calling it before it got assigned. ```UserInfoRepositoryInPeopleAPI.response = (await fetch(url, opts)).json()``` then it will be unassigned.

Comment: You should also do ```await userinfo.init(my_access_token)```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> await userinfo.getResponse()

in the place of

> await getResponse()